# C# - How to pass a type as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, types

I think it's more difficult to ask than answering the question.
I wanna ask my question with an example:
You know that we can bind an object to a DataSource, and that object could be of any type. So suppose I've bound an object of type "MyClass" to DataSource of a DataSet.
Now I send this dataset as a parameter to another class in another DLL, and in this DLL file I want to create a List<> of type of "MyClass". 
As I have not access to "MyClass" type i can use this code to get the type of DataSource:

```
_dataSet.DataSource.GetType()
```

but I can't use the code like the following to create a List of type of "MyClass":
`List<_dataSet.DataSource.GetType()> _list;`

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: What would be the point in doing this though? The only reason you want the generic list is so you can use the specific type, since you don't know the type you can't use it anyhow, might as well use a simple object array.

Comment: Reflection and generics are generally not good bed-mates... it can be done, of course, but it fights you at every step... I would consider a simpler design (and yes, there are several)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1. stick with `List<object>` or, better, we the closest known ancestor type of `_dataSet.DataSource`
2. or use a nasty reflection hack to instantiate a `List<T>` dynamically.

I'd personally resort to option (1) in most cases because it is:

- easier to use,
- readable,
- sufficiently type safe,
- universal in terms of natural code reuse.

The second option was already elaborated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newtype = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(_dataSet.DataSource.GetType());
var _list = Activator.CreateInstance(newtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a generic type using reflection:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(
    new[] { _dataSet.DataSource.GetType() }
);
var ctor = listType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
var list = ctor.Invoke(null);
```

Note that `list` will be typed as `object`.

Comment: You can nail the type down slightly more by casting to `IList`, but that's as specific as you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use reflection to instantiate a generic list of the desired type. This method should do the trick:

```
public object InstantiateGenericList( Type nodeType )
{
    Type   list        = typeof(List<>) ;
    Type   genericList = list.MakeGenericType( nodeType ) ;
    object instance    = Activator.CreateInstance( genericList ) ;

    return instance ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection, as other answers have pointed out.

Do you have control over the other class in the other DLL?  Can you make that class or the particular method that you're calling on that class generic?

```
public class SomeOtherClassInSomeOtherDLL
{
    public void DoSomethingWithData<T>(T dataSource)
    {
        // ...

        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        list.Add(dataSource);

        // ...
    }
}
```

So you would call it like this:

```
        var anotherClass = new SomeOtherClassInSomeOtherDLL();

        // ...

        anotherClass.DoSomethingWithData(_dataSet.DataSource as MyClass);
```